# What does 'c' stand for in ls -ld on device files?

Tags: command-line, ls

I was wondering what 'c' stands for in the below command result.

```
rohith@rohith-pc:~$ ls -ld /dev/null
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Jul  8 06:31 /dev/null
rohith@rohith-pc:~$
```

I could see that this 'c' is present on most of the files in /dev directory.
So can I assume that these just mean that the file is a device file?

Thanks in advance! :)